# How to set own handler events on custom js object?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, undefined, setinterval

There is an `Interval` with next usage:

```
let interval = new Interval(1000);
interval.ontick = function(progress){
    console.log('Progress:', progress);
};
interval.start(10);
```

Inside `start()` call `onTickEventHandler()` after timeout a second, but `ontick` is `undefined`.

```
function start(count) {
    _count = count;
    _intervalId = setInterval(onTickEventHandler, _timeout);
}

function onTickEventHandler() {
    if (_progress == _count) {
        reset();
        callEventHandler(onfinish);
        return;
    }

    callEventHandler(ontick, _progress++); // ontick is undefined
}
```

I tried like this

```
_intervalId = setInterval(onTickEventHandler.bind(this), _timeout);
```

`this` has my `interval.ontick`, but inside `onTickEventHandler` - `ontick` is `undefined`.

## Update

I changed `let ontick` to `function ontick` and used `this` everywhere.

Can simplify it? The target is to do like with DOM element:

```
button.onclick = function(){}
interval.ontick = function(){}
```

## Full code

```
const Interval = function (timeout) {
    const _timeout = timeout;

    let _intervalId;
    let _count;
    let _progress = 0;

    function ontick(){}
    function onpause(){}
    function onresume(){}
    function onfinish(){}

    function onTickEventHandler() {
        if (_progress == _count) {
            reset();
            callEventHandler(this.onfinish);
            return;
        }

        callEventHandler(this.ontick, _progress++);
    }

    function start(count) {
        _count = count;
        _intervalId = setInterval(onTickEventHandler.bind(this), _timeout);
    }

    function pause() {
        clearInterval(_intervalId);
        callEventHandler(this.onpause);
    }

    function resume() {
        this.start(_count);
        callEventHandler(this.onresume);
    }

    function reset() {
        clearInterval(_intervalId);
        _progress = 0;
    }

    function callEventHandler(handler, arg1){
        if (handler){
            handler(arg1);
        }
    }


    return {
        start: start,
        pause: pause,
        resume: resume,
        ontick: ontick,
        onpause: onpause,
        onresume: onresume,
        onfinish: onfinish,
    };
};
```

Comment: `callEventHandler(ontick, _progress++); // ontick is undefined` what is `ontick`? You never seem to assign it to anything.

Comment: @VLAZ at the usage section `interval.ontick = function(progress){...}`

Comment: "*this has my interval.ontick, but inside onTickEventHandler - ontick is undefined*" the `ontick` and `this.ontick` are *two different things*. They aren't interchangeable and don't point to the same thing and are completely separate - `this.ontick` is a *property* on an object, `ontick` is a *variable*. There is no relation except they happen to share a name but can easily be `this.x` and `let y`.

Comment: @VLAZ what do i change to use `interval.ontick = function(){}`?

Comment: `callEventHandler(ontick, _progress++)` -> `callEventHandler(this.ontick, _progress++)`. And you can remove `let ontick` - it's not doing anything.

Comment: @VLAZ but in this case `Interval` can has any outside: `onTick`, `tick` and other. How can I restrict only `ontick` to be called?

Comment: Then you need to pass them in at creation time or something. You're currently exposing all of these anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ I try to do analogical as `button.onclick = function() {}`. What I need do for it?